# Как передать обьекту приватный метод?

Tags: классы, ruby, объекты

```rb
class Tom

private
  def met
   puts "hi"
  end
end

pet = Tom.new
```

Как мне передать этот приватный метод обьекту класса, что бы он мог его использовать?

Comment: Задача не ясна.  Что значит «передать метод объекту класса»?

Comment: Я создал класс Tom и объект класса pet. А так же приватный метод met. И я хочу бы pet мог использовать этот метод.

Comment: Ну так он может.  Изнутри своих методов.  Опять же, не ясно, в чём вы видите проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pet.send(:met)
```

или

```
pet.send('met')
```

Метод `send` позволяет вызвать любой метод, в том числе приватный. Но приватные методы потому и приватные, что должны использоваться только внутри класса. Если у вас возникла такая необходимость, значит с большой вероятностью вы что-то делаете не так